# CSS Import Fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have 4 Fonts I need to use on a website and i have there files in my website folder

```
Baskerville.ttc
BellGothicstd-Black.otf
BellGothicstd-Bold.otf
JennaSue.ttf
```

I have tried to Import the using @Import and The fonts still do not work here is what I used:

```
@import url(../fonts/BellGothicStd-Black.otf);
@import url(../fonts/BellGothicStd-Bold.otf);
@import url(../fonts/Baskerville.ttc);
@import url(../fonts/JennaSue.ttf);
```

I also tried to use the @font-face Rule this is what I used:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'BellGothicBlack';
  src:  url('../fonts/BellGothic-Black.otf') format('OpenType'),
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'BellGothicBold';
  src:  url('../fonts/BellGothicStd-Bold.otf') format('OpenType'),
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Baskerville';
  src:  url('../fonts/Baskerville.ttc') format('OpenType'),
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'JennaSue';
  src:  url('../fonts/JennaSue.ttf') format('TrueType'),
}
```

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I think I might be missing some code I'm not really sure.

Thanks in Advance
Tom

Comment: check the network tab in your console to see if there are any errors loading the font files.

Comment: There seems to be no errors @samuel Liew

Comment: `ttc` is not `format(OpenType)` but `format(collection)`, and you are missing the fragment identifier to tell the browser which font *in* the collection to use (it's the PostScript name, see the output of `fc-scan <collection.ttc>`; `fc-scan` is part of the fontconfig tool suite, install on linux or with homebrew). Firefox doesn't appear to support TTC collections in font-face.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will need to convert the font into the correct formats for all browsers to display them.. (check rights before you do this)

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Your `@font-face` rule will also need to include all the font types...

Example:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Comment: So I need to convert all my font files to those formats and the use the above font rule to get them working?

Comment: correct, the link i provided will also supply the correct css for the fonts, you'll be able to copy this to your main CSS file and see the result.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron Works perfectly Now Upvoted and marked correct

Answer (score 0):

U need to generate font-faceto all the fonts for OS and Browser compatibility.

Font-face generator URL:http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Helvetica';
src: url('helvetica.eot');
src: url('helvetica.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
 url('helvetica.woff') format('woff'),
 url('helvetica.ttf') format('truetype'),
 url('helvetica.svg#helvetica') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
 }
```