# Wordpress - font weight varying across browsers

Tags: css, cross-browser

DUPLICATE CLARIFICATION - This question relates to cross browser differences in font weights, the question highlighted as possible duplicate relates to uploading font files correctly.

I'm uploading a site onto Wordpress using a child theme of html5blank and am getting variations of font-weights across different browsers which I'm not getting with just the stand alone front-end text files. 
This is what I mean on text for a hover effect -

**Chrome/Safari**

[image: Chrome / Safari version]

**Firefox (this is what I want)**

[image: firefox]

I've tried to use the code from the answer of this stack [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278020/font-weight-turns-lighter-on-mac-safari)

```
body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
```

But that hasn't worked. If I use `font-weight: bold;` then it works for Chrome but throws out Firefox and Safari. This is the font I'm using -

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham-Light';
    src: url('fonts/Gotham-Light.otf') format('opentype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

 body {
      font-family: 'Gotham-Light', sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;

    }
```

Is there any way I can fix this? The client is a design professional and was quite specific on stuff like this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: All you have there is the OTF font.

Comment: @scoopzilla That's all I've got. Do I need more? If so, which ones?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Import Fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32563123/css-import-fonts)

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead see my answer :)

Comment: @scoopzilla Thanks, which font types are most compatible?

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead there are 4 basic font types. I hope this helps.

Comment: @jmargolisvt Hi, are you able to remove the duplicate marker to this question? I've clarified the issue - the two questions are quite clearly different.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should have all of the font types associated with that typeface for cross-browser compatibility:

[CSS3 Web Fonts](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp)

You can actually make them here:

[Font Squirrel Webfont Generator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)

And sometimes you cannot control how browsers will handle different fonts. Safari will act totally different than Firefox, etc.

Lastly: It does help to use actual font WEIGHTS instead of the default "bold" and "light".

Example:

```
 body {
  font-family: 'Gotham-Light', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;

 }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I've uploaded all the other font types and I'm still getting differential in font weights - is there anything I can do or is this just as is?